# Error when trying to subset vector list using map2() in R

Tags: r, purrr

I am new to R's `map2()` function and I encountered a behaviour which I don't understand and I don't know where to go from here.

I want to subset a list of vectors based on a condition applied to one of the vectors. This example works perfectly fine:

`test <- list(a=c(4,5,6),b=c(23, 5, 8),c = c('sun', 'sky', 'clouds'))`

`f <- test$b == 8`

`map2(.x = test,.y = f, ~ .x[f])`

Output:

```
[1] 6

$b
[1] 8

$c
[1] "clouds"
```

However, when I try to add an additional vector to `test` it throws an error:

`test <- list(a=c(4,5,6),b=c(23, 5, 8),c = c('sun', 'sky', 'clouds'), d = c('winter', 'summer', 'spring'))`

`f <- test$b == 8`

`map2(.x = test,.y = f, ~ .x[f])`

Expected Output:

```
[1] 6

$b
[1] 8

$c
[1] "clouds"

$d
[1] "spring"
```

Actual Output:

```
Error: Mapped vectors must have consistent lengths:
* `.x` has length 4
* `.y` has length 3
```

I am aware that it is related to the fact that my number of vectors is unequal the length of f, but I don't understand why this would be a problem. I'd really appreciate any suggestions on how I could get my goal output in the second scenario.

Thank you!

Comment: In the function you are not using `.y`, only `.x`. So, `map` is the function you should be using. This works on both cases:  `map(.x = test, ~ .x[f])`.

Comment: Hi thank you so much, it works perfectly now! I just tried it with `map2(.x = test,.y = f, ~ .x[.y]` and it still gives me the same error. What exactly is the difference between `map2(.x = test,.y = f, ~ .x[.y]` and `map(.x = test, ~ .x[f])`? Just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: `map2` takes 2 vectors (called .x and .y) of the same length, and a function that takes 2 arguments. It calls the function with the first element of the .x and the first element of .y, then with the second element of .x and the second element of .y, and so on.
In your case, you provided a formula that uses only one argument, which is okay. What is wrong is that the vectors .x and .y must be of the same length.

Comment: Ah ok I see, that makes perfect sense. Thank you very much!